# Confused with Pickle Function

Tags: python

so i am making a game for my sister and currently a terrible Python coder and here is my code:

```
#The Pet Game
Coins = '0'
Gems = '0'
Eggs = "Rotten Egg, Basic Egg, The u-can't-find-it-that-easily-egg :D, The Magical Egg :3, The Unicorn Egg :), the SUPREME EGG"
Limited_Eggs = 'Covid-19 Egg'
coins_added = '0'
gems_added = '0'
if coins_added > '0':
    print("You recieved", coins_added,"coins")
    Coins + coins_added
if gems_added > '0':
    print("You recieved", gems_added,"gems")
    Gems + gems_added
import random
import time
import pickle
Inventory = '1'
Player_Name = input("Hello, before we get started, i need to know your name. What is it? ")
time.sleep(2)
print("Hello there", Player_Name,"and welcome to the world of pets(Is chessy dont judge)")
time.sleep(1)
print("to save your progress type 'save' (caps sensitive) and to load it type load (the save file is called unicornsrdebest.dat btw in case u wanted to know)")
time.sleep(1)
print("To buy eggs type /eggs (caps sensitive) and to chec out inventory type inventory (also caps sensitive)")
time.sleep(1)
Action = input("What would you like to do now")
if Action == 'save':
    Fi = input("What would you like your save file to be called?")
    pickle.dump([Coins, Gems, Inventory], open("unicornsrdebest.dat", "wb"))
if Action == ("load"):
    pickle.load(open("unicornsrdebest.dat", "rb")) 
if Action == '/eggs':
    print(Eggs)
```

i am very confused but the code does not work as every time I try to run it and attempt the save or load option it just quits the program. Please also use simple language as I have started python not that long ago.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what is the error you are getting?

Comment: whenever i get up to the Action variable input and put in save or load it just quits the program

Comment: What do you *expect* it to do after that? There's nothing after you do that, so the program terminates.

Comment: ok i didn't know that

Comment: You need to write `Coins, Gems, Inventory = pickle.load(....)`.  For now, you're just reading the pickle file, and throwing away the result.   Please also correct the spelling of "receive", even though you didn't ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a fun starting project! I made a couple changes to your code:

```py
#The Pet Game

import random
import time
import pickle

# variables
coins = 0
gems = 0
inventory = 1

eggs = ["Rotten Egg", 
        "Basic Egg", 
        "The u-can't-find-it-that-easily-egg :D", 
        "The Magical Egg :3", "The Unicorn Egg :)", 
        "the SUPREME EGG"]

limited_eggs = ['Covid-19 Egg']

if coins > 0:
    print("You recieved ", str(coins), " coins")

if gems > 0:
    print("You recieved", str(gems) ,"gems")

player_name = input("Hello, before we get started, i need to know your name. What is it? ")
time.sleep(2)

print("Hello there", player_name, "and welcome to the world of pets(Is chessy dont judge)")
time.sleep(1)

print("to save your progress type 'save' (caps sensitive) and to load it type load (the save file is called unicornsrdebest.dat btw in case u wanted to know)")
time.sleep(1)

print("To buy eggs type /eggs (caps sensitive) and to chec out inventory type inventory (also caps sensitive)")
time.sleep(1)

action = input("What would you like to do now: ")

while(action != 'quit'):
    
    if action == 'save':
        fi = input("What would you like your save file to be called? ")
        pickle.dump([coins, gems, inventory], open(fi, "wb"))
        
    if action == ("load"):
        fi = input("What file would you like to load? ")
        coins, gems, inventory = pickle.load(open(fi, "rb"))
        
    if action == '/eggs':
        print(eggs)
        
    action = input("What would you like to do now: ")
```

Let me break down what I did so far.

```
import random
import time
import pickle

# variables
coins = 0
gems = 0
inventory = 1
```

It's standard to put the libraries you import at top, followed by your variables. It's good for organization. I also made your variables integers instead of strings because you will be counting your coins and gems.

```py
eggs = ["Rotten Egg", 
        "Basic Egg", 
        "The u-can't-find-it-that-easily-egg :D", 
        "The Magical Egg :3", "The Unicorn Egg :)", 
        "the SUPREME EGG"]

limited_eggs = ['Covid-19 Egg']
```

I made the eggs and limited_eggs lists, because they are multiple items.

```py
while(action != 'quit'):

    if action == 'save':
        fi = input("What would you like your save file to be called? ")
        pickle.dump([coins, gems, inventory], open(fi, "wb"))

    if action == ("load"):
        fi = input("What file would you like to load?")
        pickle.load(open(fi, "rb"))

    if action == '/eggs':
        print(eggs)

    action = input("What would you like to do now: ")
```

I made your if statements a **while loop** so you can continue playing the game. It will stop when you enter 'quit'.

```py
    if action == ("load"):
        fi = input("What file would you like to load?")
        coins, gems, inventory = pickle.load(open(fi, "rb"))
```

I think this is where you were having trouble. I changed it so the coins, gems and inventory are changed once a file is loaded.

Next time on this community, show only the lines of code you are having trouble with. Another community you might want to check out is [r/learnpython](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/). Have fun with this project!

Comment: tysm thi was exactly what i was looking for!!

Comment: um i was curious but what does str mean? like does it do something special if you put `str(blahblahblah)`?

Comment: The `str()` function converts an object to a string. For example, str(4) converts the integer 4 -> "4". [source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str)

Comment: You're welcome! Also please click the "accept this answer" mark if you found this post to be helpful. Thank you